# How do I use the two meaning of the word "just" differently?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

The English word "just" could mean "now" or "finally," for example:

> I just finished my homework.

Does it mean "I finished my homework ***now***" or "I ***finally*** finished my homework"?

How do I use the two meanings differently?

Comment: *Just* has many shades of meaning and usages, but they all carry the meaning of exactness or near exactness.  So if you just finished your homework, then the time of finishing is only a little bit ago from now.  *Finally* implies that your homework was a long chore.  But you could have just finished an easy assignment.

Answer (score 2):

The adverb [***finally***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/finally) *mainly* has two meanings:

> After a long time, typically when there has been ***difficulty or delay***
>
> As ***the last in a series*** of related events or items

It is not synonymous with [*just*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/just) which means:

> Very recently; in the immediate past

If there is the right context, *just* could be interpreted as *finally*, but their meanings are different and they are not interchangeable.

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

Comment: **I just finished my homework.** may have two "sub-meanings", (1) as per above, in the very recent past, and also (2) with no time to spare - right on a deadline. So: "I just finished my homework before the final due date.", or more commonly "I just caught the bus." (ie, I nearly missed it, rather than I caught it very recently).

Comment: @Cargill Yes, you are right. It will all depend on context.